# Use UTF-8 encoding mapshaper

Tags: shapefile, geojson, json, topojson, mapshaper

I want to convert a `json` into `topoJson` using mapshaper.org.
The `json` file I am using has world wide names in it, hence is encoded in `UTF-8`.

However, when I upload the file on mapshaper and then click `export - TopoJson`, it saves it in an encoding which encodes some of the letters wrong.

Is there a way to tell mapshaper to encode in `UTF-8`?

Would be interesting to know how to export any file edited with mapshaper in an specific encoding.

Answer (score 1):

JSON in using only unicode as defined in http://json.org/

> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in
>   double quotes, using backslash escapes. A character is represented as
>   a single character string. A string is very much like a C or Java
>   string.

If Mapshaper is changing the strings that you have in the source JSON into something else it feels like a bug. However, you should give some examples about what happens.

Comment: I downloaded the shapefile `admin-1` from here http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/ and saved it with `qgis` as `geojson` and uploaded that one to `mapshaper`

Comment: Please try to make it easy for us. Take one feature from your JSON and the same as converted into topoJSON with wrong characters. Or at least put your JSON somewhere for downloading.